# Why does GSM use full-duplex while cell phones have only one antenna?

Tags: gsm, duplex

According to [this website](http://gsmfordummies.com/intro/intro.shtml#fdma):

> Although GSM operates in duplex (separate frequencies for transmit and receive), the mobile station does not transmit and receive at the same time. A switch is used to toggle the antenna between the transmitter and receiver.

What, then, is the advantage of using separate channels for two-way communication?  Communications can never go both ways at the same time; why have them separated (broadcast channels aside)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One reason is to help with radio planning - if powerful cell antenna's (i.e. the base station antenna's) broadcast on the same frequency they received on, then they would have a hard time 'hearing' the relatively weak broadcasts from the phones, over the relatively strong signals from neighboring cell antennas.

Answer (score -1):

"...GSM operates in duplex (separate frequencies for transmit and receive), *the mobile station does not transmit and receive at the same time*."

That's called half-duplex.  It's done to save bandwidth and battery power, and to make cell phone conversations more difficult.